# Inputting textual numbers in Java

Tags: java

Hi I am new to Java so i had a doubt regarding it,

Suppose I ask the user to input a number and rather than putting in "1" he types in "one". Would there be anyway to incorporate this into the code? I mean both '1' and 'one' being same inputs?

Comment: Not really a Java question - do you mean that you want the program to understand numbers written as text? All numbers, or just small ones? Does the program need to understand "five million nine hundred and seventy-eight thousand and ninety six. Point four two." ?

Comment: Do you need this for only a few numbers or do you need a general solution (for any number) ?

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built into Java's standard libraries to convert from words to numbers (or vice versa). Bear in mind that such a library would almost certainly want to support multiple languages, with various rules for expressing numbers ("two thousand and twelve" and "twenty twelve" being two examples of how 2012 can be expressed just in English). There may well be third party libraries available, or if you only need to cope with a very specific subset of numbers, you may want to just populate a `Map<String, Integer>`.